# iOS app to exchange images/videos between two idevices

Tags: ios, xcode, sample, uidevice

I am new to `iOS development`, I want to write an `iOS` app that can exchange images between two devices. Can anybody direct me to good tutorial/sample code?

Answer (score 1):

IOS 7 introduces a great feature AirDrop. With **AirDrop**, you can easily share data with other nearby iOS devices. Also this feature allows you to share photos, videos, contacts, URLs, Passbook passes, app listings on the App Store, media listings on iTunes Store, location in Maps, etc. 
You can also programatically share photos with the help of AirDrop. Here is an example for displaying the AirDrop activity

```
UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];

NSArray *excludedActivities = @[UIActivityTypePostToTwitter, UIActivityTypePostToFacebook,
                                UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,
                                UIActivityTypeMessage, UIActivityTypeMail,
                                UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,
                                UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                                UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList, UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
                                UIActivityTypePostToVimeo, UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo];
controller.excludedActivityTypes = excludedActivities;

[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

See the tutorial [here](http://www.appcoda.com/ios7-airdrop-programming-tutorial/)

Comment: If you want to go deeper into that, there are the Multipeer connectivity APIs https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: I appreciate the answers but, I am looking for images sending and receiving via socket programming